# How to print an array without the count

Tags: php, arrays

So i'm trying to write this php script to output differences in text files. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$file1 = "list2.txt";
$file2 = "list1.txt";
$lines1 = file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$result = array_diff($lines2, $lines1);
print_r($result);
?>
```

I want this to echo out just the leftover words without the [0] => on every line, i just want the word, not the numbering. I've tried using "pre" tags and it doesn't work.

Comment: use `echo implode("", $result);`

Comment: It just mashed the words all together so i added "\n" to           echo implode("\n", $result);
Thanks Azad, that worked!

Comment: yes, good, I left this for u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or [join](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) function

```
echo implode("\n", $result);
```

Or

```
echo join("\n", $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` is mostly for debug purposes, not display.
U can do

```
foreach($result as $r) print($r);
```

OR

`echo join(' ',$result);`

Comment: Why use an Alias of the original function `implode`?

Comment: I'd +1 for 'mostly for debug', but the `U` counts for around negative infinity points...

Answer (score 0):

you can use php function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with break html tag

like below

```
echo implode('<br>', $result);
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Print_r (and var_dump) are primarily for debug outputting.  For your diff you want to do something like

```
print implode(PHP_EOL,$result);
```

If your output header is text/plain, then HTML tags will not render as HTML but will be displayed as text in the page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch the array elements one by one.then use it.so to fetch each element one by one u may use foreach:like

```
foreach($result as $x)
{
   echo $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using file might not be efficient when dealing with large files ....

```
$a = "list1.txt";
$b = "list2.txt";

$fpA = fopen($a, "r");
$fpB = fopen($b, "r");

$i = 0;

while(! feof($fpA)) {
    $i ++;
    $x = trim(fgets($fpA));
    $y = trim(fgets($fpB));
    if ($x !== $y) {
        printf("#%d: %s<br />\n", $i, $y);
    }
}
```

Output

```
#8: 2cc021a8f87e1defeb5d0a1d43a0FFFFF
```